# Programmatically install "non compatible" driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, driver, wdk, devcon

I want to install signed driver but unfortunately the .inf file does not contain the correct hardware IDs. (incompatible driver)
I can install the driver manually like described here:

[Force installing incompatible .inf driver in Windows Server 2019 Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58641456/1361096)

- Right Click Update Driver in Device Manager
- "Browse my computer for computer software”
- “Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer”
- Select “Have Disk…” and point to the driver folder

Now I'm looking for a way to do the same from script or code.

**What I've tried so far:**

- I've tried to install the driver with `devcon install -r <inf file> <device id>` without success (error without any log).
- patching the inf file with hardware Ids would break the driver signature and this is therefore not a good solution
- PnPUtil: This adds the driver to the driver store, but because it is not compatible, the driver is not installed

**It would also help to have answers or comments to the following questions:**

- Where can i get more logs from devcon to see detailed error descriptions
- Can I somehow sign the driver by my self after patching the inf file?
- Any other Ideas what i could try?

Comment: Search in `C:\Windows\INF` for logs. You are looking for `setupapi.dev` and `setupapi.setup` etc. files.